# Derive from base class and override functions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here's a portion of the standard `Label` control in WinForms:

```
public class Label : Control
{
       protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
       {
           ...
       }
}
```

I'd like to override the OnTextChanged event but I'm not sure of the best way.

Should I derive a subclass from Label class and then override the function like this?

```
public class Class1 : Label
{
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("S");
    }
}
```

If so, how and where should I add this class?

If not, how can I override functions which are defined inside a control?

Comment: Your code is fine... Is your question "how to use my new `Class1` on my form instead of instances of `Label`"?

Comment: After you compile project, your Class1 control will be in Toolbox, at the top of it

Comment: Are you overriding the control only to do this? If so you should probably assign an event handler to the OnTextChanged event instead.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes you're right, if the code in correct, so how I can use my label defenition in my project?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov for example sth like this: Class1 newlabel = new Class1(); //then add the newlabel to winform UI // then use it ! and How? thanks

Comment: Once you build the project, your class that subclasses `Label` should show up in the ToolBox just like a normal label does. Then drag it onto your form just like a regular label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way you can override the method for control. As you have done is absolutely right but detailed implementation is here.

This is the form part

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        MyLabel newLable;
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newLable = new MyLabel();
            newLable.Height = 30;
            newLable.Width = 40;
            newLable.Text = "hello";
            this.Controls.Add(newLable);

        }       
    }
}
```

You can use MyLabel from toolbox also.

And MyLabel class is

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

   public class MyLabel:Label
    {

       public MyLabel()
       {

       }
       protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnClick(e);
           MessageBox.Show("Label Clicked");
       }

    }
}
```